# Problema con sqslistener de aws con anotaciones

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws

Estoy usando Spring Boot 3, spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs 3.0.1.

Los mensajes de la cola no se eliminan a pesar de que el método ha funcionado correctamente.

Necesito poder borrar los mensajes manuales, esta versión de sqs o aws no tiene el borrado, he intentado recuperar el acknolowe o como se escriba en el método pero me da el error de no poder hacerlo manualmente, entonces Estoy seguro de que necesito agregar algún tipo de bean en la configuración, pero probé varias cosas y casi todas son para la versión anterior.

Alguien ha tenido este problema ???